# Normalization of a data with skewed distibution

Tags: normalization, deep-learning, skewness

I have a data set which has 10 features (columns). I want to normalize the data before dealing it with deep learning.

Each column has a different distribution but overall they are all skewed!

1) which normalization method should i use?

2) can I use different normalization methods on different columns or should it be the same for all ?

Comment: Are they all positive?  Are they right skewed?  Typical transformations for positive, right skewed variables are any that bring down large values, so square roots, logs, etc. Or log(x+c) for a small value of c, if there are zeros in the data.

Comment: @AlaskaRon they are all positive but they are not all right skewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is useful to keep in mind the usual reasons for transforming features (assuming Gaussian errors): reshaping their PDFs to enhance the symmetry of the error structure. It is not a violation of any deep learning or multivariate analytic assumption to apply different transformations ("normalizations") to your data. In other words, nowhere is it written that you have to use the same transformation for every feature. Sometimes it is convenient to do so, as with multiplicative, log-log modeling, but it is definitely not required.

It's impossible to recommend a specific transformation in the abstract -- it is totally a data-driven decision. Textbooks have been devoted to the seemingly limitless number of mathematical functions that are available to be applied. Some common transformations will compress the PDF, e.g., square roots or natural logs, while others extend it, e.g., polynomials. Extreme valued PDFs can benefit from functions such as the inverse hyperbolic sine or Lambert's *W*.

The biggest problem with many of these "solutions" is that you can lose the meaning of the original unit in which the variable was scaled. This may not be an issue for deep learning algorithms but can be a problem for insights-focused statistical analysis. In this instance, the cure can be worse than the disease, particularly given that Gaussian models are quite robust to violations of the assumptions.

Comment: you said about "normalization can lead to loose the meaning of original unit". the package that i am using for deeplearning (H2o) gives me MSE for the models that i build. once i built a model with no normalization and the MSE was around 400000 ! so i was thinking if i must normalize the data, because MSE is the only tool that i have for performance of my model. how should i deal with large values of MSE (caused by large values of data) ?

Comment: Although this is helpful, some emphases are debatable. The most common reason for transformation in my experience is a goal of  linearity. Symmetry or skewness is not nearly so big a deal; no regression assumption focuses on marginal distribution of predictors and Gaussian or even symmetric errors is the least important  assumption in the linear model. Although more can be said it should minimally be added that a strong theory can be major grounds for a transformation, as when as exponential change is contemplated,  or even when log transformation is used because predictions must be positive.

Comment: @Nimakhin  Your comment about the extreme valued residuals from your model suggests the possibility that the outliers are not in the predictors, they're in Y or dependent variable. Predictor transformations won't impact things all that much in this case. If you were working in a traditional regression context, there would be a few additional options to try in blunting the extremas. 1) Robust techniques such as quantile regression provide a bulwark against extreme valued observations. 2) Assuming different underlying probabilistic error distributions would also improve fit, e.g., Cauchy or Levy